# EntityFramework 1 to 0, 1 or many relationship

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I am struggling to create a relationship in Entity framework between three tables..
I am developing WPF application using C#, Sqlite 3.0 and Entity Framework 6.

I have Following tables(classes):

1. Investor
2. Investment
3. ImageStore

I want to create a model so that Investor and Investment (and future other classes) can store either 0, 1 or Many images.. (as it is obvious from class names that Investor can have only one profile image and Investment class can have multiple images)
My ImageStore class looks something like this:

```
public class ImageStore : PropertyChangedNotification
    {
        [Key]
        public int ImageStoreId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ImageFile { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Byte[] ImageBlob { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int FileSize { get; set; }


        //public virtual ImageData ImageData { get; set; }
    }
```

In order to create 1 to 0,1 or Many relationship, I created one more intermediate table called: ImageData as seen below (I don't know whether it is really a good approach but that is only what I can think of right now..)

```
public class ImageData : PropertyChangedNotification
    {
        [Key]
        public int ImageDataId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Investment")]
        public long? InvestmentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Investor")]
        public long? InvestorId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ImageStore")]
        public int ImageStoreId { get; set; }

        public virtual ImageStore ImageStore { get; set; }

        public virtual Investment Investment { get; set; }

       public virtual Investor Investor { get; set; }
    }
```

My Investor class looks like this:

```
public class Investor : PropertyChangedNotification
    {
        [Key]
        public long InvestorId { get; set; }        

        [NotMapped]
        [ForeignKey("ImageData")]
        public List<int> ImageDataList { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ImageData> ImageDataCollection { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Investment> Investments { get; set; }        
    }
```

My Investment Class Looks like this:

```
 public class Investment : PropertyChangedNotification
    {
        [Key]
        public long InvestmentId { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("Investor")]
       [Required]
       public long FirstInvestorId { get; set; }       


        [NotMapped]
        [ForeignKey("ImageData")]
        public List<int> ImageDataList { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ImageData> ImageDataCollection { get; set; }       

        public virtual Investor Investor { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Required (ErrorMessage = "First Investor is Required")]
        public Investor FirstInvestor { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my related fluent configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // MyData Database does not pluralize table names
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Investor>().HasOptional(s => s.ImageDataCollection);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Investment>().HasOptional(s => s.ImageDataCollection);
            //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        }
```

When I start debugging the application, I get the following error:

1. ImageData_Investment_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ImageData_Investment_Source' in relationship 'ImageData_Investment'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'
2. ImageData_Investor_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ImageData_Investor_Source' in relationship 'ImageData_Investor'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'

Can someone please suggest me either a solution to this problem and/or optimal approach to achieve what I need, I really will appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: Try changing `int?` in FKs to `long?` (or `long` in PKs to `int`)

Comment: After making the changes in Class (O mad InvestoerId and InvestmentId in ImageData class to be long), my 2nd and fourth errors went away and now I left with Error# 1 and 3

Comment: Do you have related fluent configuration not shown here?

Comment: Ivan, I added the related fluent configuration and also updated the datatype for two properties on ImageStore class.

Comment: Ok, either remove that fluent configuration (since you are using data annotations), or make it match your model (because currently it doesn't). e.g. `modelBuilder.Entity<Investor>().HasMany(e => e.ImageDataCollection).WithOptional(e => e.Investor).HasForeignKey(e => e.InvestorId);`. Similar to the other.

Comment: How this can be achieved using data annotations? Since I am very heavily using data annotations for other purpose as well (like validation). I then can remove the fluent? What changes I need to make to my Model to make the Data Annotation work?

Comment: I think all you need is to comment (or delete) the two lines in the above code inside `OnModelCreating`. Because you already have `ForeignKey` annotations in your classes, they should be sufficient for this type of relationship.

Comment: Ivan, One little thing.. My relationship from ImageStroe to ImageData is not working. I declared public virtual ImageData ImageData { get; set; } in my ImageStore class and it throws an error. Since my ImageData already has ImageStoreId, it should give me the ImageData from ImageStore

Comment: It's actually not a little thing due to some EF limitations of `one-to-one` relationships. You'd better merge `ImageStore` and `ImageData` in a single class (table).

Comment: Ok, finally I decided to get rid of ImageData entity all together and create InvestorId and InvestmentId in ImageStore Entity. Now while saving Investor entity, I am trying to insert an ImageStore entity by using following: Investor.ImageStore.Add(imageData); where imageData is an ImageStore object. I receive Object reference error since Investor object is still not saved and InvestorId is 0. Can you please suggest the solution for that?

Comment: Even I tried the following:
`dbContext.ImageStore.Add(imageData);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
Investor.ImageStore.Add(imageData);` with no success. When I do AddOrUpdate on Investor object, I ideally should be able to add the ImageStore object to it and then saveChanges should automatically create the ImageStore Entity

Comment: You'd better delete this question and post another one with the latest model and the code to reproduce the new issue. It's hard to follow here with all the changes made.

Comment: Ivan, Can you please post your comment to remove the Fluent lines as solution since I don't want your effort to get wasted providing me with a great help. I will accept that as an answer and open a new thread to discuss a new problem. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fluent configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Investor>().HasOptional(s => s.ImageDataCollection);
modelBuilder.Entity<Investment>().HasOptional(s => s.ImageDataCollection);
```

is incomplete.

Since the you already have the necessary data annotations and navigation / FK properties, you can simply remove it. Or if you want to provide fluent configuration (which I personally prefer because it allows you to specify everything explicitly and not rely on conventions and specifically for relationships, not so intuitive `ForegnKey` and `InverseProperty` data annotations), then you should make sure it reflects exactly the presense/absence of the navigation and FK properties in the involved entities.

The correct fluent configuration reflecting your model so far is like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Investor>()
    .HasMany(e => e.ImageDataCollection)
    .WithOptional(e => e.Investor)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.InvestorId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Investment>()
    .HasMany(e => e.ImageDataCollection)
    .WithOptional(e => e.Investment)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.InvestmentId);
```